# Host multicontainer application on Bluemix?

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud, docker-compose

I have an application that makes use docker-compose file to stand up on docker environment. Is there a way i can  port/publish this  multi-container application to IBM Bluemix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure! Try out this tutorial to get started:
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_single_ui.html#container_compose_intro

Comment: what if it has to create docker machine.. does Bluemix support creation of docker machine?

Comment: No docker machine is not supported. Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 1):

The IBM Containers service has two distinct flavors you can use presently. You can either use Container Groups (backed by docker containers, the service also supports docker-compose files).

Your comment above seems to indicate that you want to create a docker container? You can do that  from the service too. If you want to run docker machine, you will not be able to do that on the first service with container groups, or on the kubernetes service (currently. It is still in beta).

The new version of the service is container orchestration backed by Kubernetes, and managed by SoftLayer. You can use this in much the same way you use docker-compose, except your docker container cloud is managed by kubernetes rather than you, the user.